# Получение имени элемента JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть html:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="main-image-form">
    <input name="image_url">
    <button type="submit" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="save btn btn-warning">
        <b>-100 G</b> <img src="reload.png'">
    </button>
    <div name="main" onclick="backgroundPreview(this);"></div>
    <button name="btn"></button>
</form>
```

И JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#main-image-form').submit(function(e){
        // some code
    });
});

function backgroundPreview(elem) {
    console.log(elem);
    console.log(elem.name);
}
```

**Во-первых** - первая JS функция срабатывает даже при нажатии на `button`, у которого `name="btn"`. Не пойму почему. Судя по функции срабатывать должна только при нажатии на кнопку формы типа `submit`

**Во-вторых** - при нажатии на `div`, у которого `name="main"`, вызывается функция `backgroundPreview`, которой из html передается объект элемента. Сам объект в консоль печатается. А вот вместо его параметра `name` в консоль выводится `undefined`. Почему? Ведь у данного элемента `div` есть атрибут `name`. Если же этот `div` сменить на `button`, то имя будет печататься, но тогда будет вызываться первая JS функция, как было описано в первом пункте, а этого мне нельзя допустить.

Что я могу сделать для того, чтобы при нажатии на `div` вызвалась только одна вторая JS функция, и я мог бы получить атрибут `name` у этого `div` из JS?

Comment: 1. "Судя по функции" срабатывает он при отправке формы (событие submit); 2. Элементу div не свойственен атрибут name. Атрибуты, не свойственные элементу, можно получить с помощью `el.getAttribute(attribute_name)`

Comment: По поводу первого пункта - если кнопка находится внутри тега `form`, то нужно явно прописывать `type="button"`, т.к. по умолчанию стоит `type="submit"`

Comment: Первый комментарий ответил на второй вопрос, второй на первый

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Во-первых** - первая JS функция срабатывает даже при нажатии на `button`, у которого `name="btn"`. Не пойму почему. Судя по функции срабатывать должна только при нажатии на кнопку формы типа submit

Кнопка `<input type="button|submit">` или `<button></button>` в `form` будет являться кнопкой отправки этой самой формы.

Чтобы приведённый код работал должным образом, используйте тег `type="button"`, дла кнопки с артибутом `name="btn"`.

---

> **Во-вторых** - при нажатии на `div`, у которого `name="main"`, вызывается функция `backgroundPreview`, которой из `html` передается объект элемента. Сам объект в консоль печатается. А вот вместо его параметра `name` в консоль выводится `undefined`. Почему? Ведь у данного элемента `div` есть атрибут `name`. Если же этот `div` сменить на button, то имя будет печататься, но тогда будет вызываться первая `JS` функция, как было описано в первом пункте, а этого мне нельзя допустить.

Как вам уже ответили в комментариях, для `div` нет атрибута `name`, используйте, допустим `data-name`. В Jquery получайте данные атрибута `data-name` через `.data('name')`.

Пример:

```js
$('#dsa').on('click', function(){
  $('.asd').each(function(){
    let dataName = $(this).data('name');
    console.info(dataName);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="asd" data-name="1">one</div>
<div class="asd" data-name="#0f0">green</div>
<div class="asd" data-name="#id1">id1</div>
<br>
<button id="dsa">Получить все data-name</button>
```